# Manipulation with the following infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation, power-series, quantum-mechanics

Calculating some observable, I obtained the following-like converges sum
$$
S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{\min(n,k)} \frac{x^n}{n!} \frac{y^k}{k!} F(p),
$$
where $F$ - some function which explicitly depends only on $p$ index. It is obvious that
$$
S \neq e^x e^y \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} F(p).
$$

But, probably, there are any methods how to manipulate such types of sums?  Is it possible to somehow make a summation over $n$ and $k$, redefining the upper limit for the last sum and the function $F$?

To me it looks like, this expression cannot be significantly simplified further, but maybe I don't know some techniques?

Comment: Can you give some specific examples of $F$ that you're interested in?

Comment: @Arkady In my case this function satisfies some differential equation, so, it cannot be expressed in a simple form.

Comment: If you don't give people information on $F(p)$ there is no way to find a solution because all you have is a generic McLaurin series with the coefficients unknown.  It could be any function of $xy$.  Also are you sure $x$ and $y$ are both raised to the same power $n$ ?

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine Oh, pardon, it was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: Just in case you don't already know, we also have $$S = \sum_{p=0}^\infty F(p) \biggl( \sum_{n=p}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \biggr) \biggl( \sum_{k=p}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k!} \biggr)$$ (assuming the sum converges absolutely for instance). This form at least might allow for some input from the community even without knowing anything about $F$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yeah, I think it can help, thank you!